# Склонение названий небесных тел

Tags: склонение

Здравствуйте! У Урана есть спутники с такими названиями: Оберон, Пак, Купидон. Как верно написать: "на спутнике ОберонЕ", "на спутнике ПакЕ", "на спутнике КупидонЕ" или же их названия стоит оставить неизменными - "на спутнике Оберон", "на спутнике Пак" и далее.

Answer (score 3):

Открываем справочник Розенталя и читаем:

Не согласуются в падеже с определяемым словом астрономические названия: *движение ракеты к планете Венера; орбита планеты Юпитер; яркий свет звезды Сириус*.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что астрономические названия при наличии приложения не склоняются, вот например: "Расскажем о планете Юпитер на доступном для детей языке".

При этом надо учитывать, что это цитата из популярного издания, в специальной же литературе астрономические названия при наличии родового слова тем более не должны склоняться.

Это связано с необходимостью  сохранения точности в наименовании такого имени собственного. (Подобное правило действует в отношении географических названий).

Comment: Но в то же время названия планет ведь склоняются. "На орбите Юпитера", к примеру. Или вот еще из книги: "Вокруг Меркурия наблюдается тонкая газовая оболочка..." Или это немного другие примеры?

Comment: В приведенных примерах нет родового наименования "планета", тогда название, конечно, склоняется. Для сравнения: на орбите Юпитера - на орбите планеты Юпитер.

Comment: Понятно, значит надо писать либо так: "На Обероне есть каньоны", либо так: "На спутнике Оберон есть каньоны". 
 
Кстати, а в кавычки название спутника во втором случае брать не надо?

Comment: Нет, наличие кавычек с родовым словом  не связано. Кажется, кавычки в астрономии вообще редко применяются, вот, например, некоторые названия: альфа Весов, туманность Андромеды, созвездие Южный Крест, созвездие Большая Медведица, галактика Млечный Путь.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо большое за помощь!